# trouble understanding advanced pointer arithmatic syntax

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Lets say we are given the next setting:

```
int (*p)[9];
```

1. is it a regular pointer, or some kind of a special pointer to a block of memory that is `9*sizeof(int)` big?
2. how do I refer to such syntax?
3. lets say I have a given matrix:

```
int mat[200][9];
int (*p)[9] = mat;
```

how would pointer arithmetic work with it, for example, if we were to increase p

4. how do I cast to such type?
5. the next code's output is `2 5` and I think that it has a link to the special syntax I've shown above. can someone explain to me why isn't the output `2 1`?

```
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);
    printf("%d %d", *(a+1), *(ptr-1));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the basic rules for pointer declarations:

```
T *p;              // p is a pointer to T
T *ap[N];          // ap is an array of pointers to T
T *fp();           // fp is a function returning a pointer to T

T (*pa)[N];        // pa is a pointer to an array of T
T (*pf)();         // pf is a function returning a pointer to T

T * const p;       // p is a const pointer to T - *p is writable, but p is not
const T *p;        // p is a non-const pointer to const T - p is writable, but *p is not
T const *p;        // same as above
const T * const p; // p is a const pointer to const T - neither p nor *p are writable
T const * const p; // same as above
```

To read a hairy declaration, find the leftmost identifier and work your way out per the rules above, applying them recursively to any function parameters.  For example, here's how the declaration of the `signal` function in the C standard library breaks down:

```
       signal                                       -- signal
       signal(                          )           -- is a function taking
       signal(    sig                   )           --   parameter sig
       signal(int sig                   )           --   is an int
       signal(int sig,        func      )           --   parameter func
       signal(int sig,      (*func)     )           --   is a pointer to
       signal(int sig,      (*func)(   ))           --     a function taking
       signal(int sig,      (*func)(   ))           --       unnamed parameter
       signal(int sig,      (*func)(int))           --       is an int
       signal(int sig, void (*func)(int))           --     returning void
     (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))          -- returning a pointer to
     (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(   )     --   a function taking
     (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(   )     --     unnamed parameter
     (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int)     --     is an int
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);    --   returning void
```

You can build more complex pointer types through substitution.  For example, if you want to declare a function that returns a pointer to an array, you can build it as

```
T     a     [N];    // a is an array of T
      |
  +---+----+
  |        |
T (*  pa   )[N];    // pa is a pointer to an array of T 
      |
     ++--+
     |   |
T (* fpa() )[N];    // fpa is a function returning a pointer to an array of T
```

If you want an array of pointers to functions that return pointers to `T`, then you can build it as

```
 T *     p           ;       // p is a pointer to T
         |
         +----------+
         |          |
 T *     fp        ();       // fp is a function returning pointer to T
         |
     +---+-----+
     |         |
 T * (*  pf    )   ();       // pf is a pointer to a function returning pointer to T
         |
        ++---+
        |    |
 T * (* apf[N] )   ();       // apf is an array of pointers to functions returning pointer to T
```

---

Pointer arithmetic is done in terms of *objects*, not bytes.  If `p` stores the address of an object of type `T`, then `p+1` yields the address of the next object of that type.  If `pa` stores the address of an N-element array of `T`, then `pa+1` yields the address of the next N-element array of `T`.

In your code

```
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);
    printf("%d %d", *(a+1), *(ptr-1));
    return 0;
}
```

the expression `&a + 1` yields the address of the next 5-element array of `int` following `a`.  This address value is cast to `int *`, so it's treated as the address of the first `int` following the last element of `a`.  A diagram may help:

```
 int[5]        int           int *
 ------        ---           -----
        +---+        +---+        +---+
     a: |   |  a[0]: | 1 |   ptr: |   |
        + - +        +---+        +---+
        |   |  a[1]: | 2 |          |
        + - +        +---+          |
        |   |  a[2]: | 3 |          |
        + - +        +---+          |
        |   |  a[3]: | 4 |          |
        + - +        +---+          |
        |   |  a[4]: | 5 |          |
        +---+        +---+          |
 a + 1: |   |        | ? | <--------+
        + - +        +---+
        |   |        | ? |
        + - +        +---+
         ...          ...
```

The *expressions* `a` and `a+1` have type `int [5]`, each `a[i]` has type `int`, and `ptr` has type `int *`.

Thus, `ptr-1` yields the address of `a[4]`.

---

Remember that C declaration syntax mirrors expression syntax - if you have a pointer to an array named `pa` and you want to access the `i`'th element of the pointed-to array, you have to dereference `pa` and then subscript the result (assume `T` is `int` for this example):

```
printf( "indexed value = %d\n", (*pa)[i] );
```

In both expressions and declarations, postfix operators `[]` and `()` have higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*pa[i]` would be parsed as `*(pa[i])`, which isn't what we want in this case.  We need to explicitly group the `*` operator with `pa` so we dereference the right thing.

The type of the *expression* `(*pa)[i]` is `int`, so the declaration of `pa` is written as

```
int (*pa)[N];
```

Thus, the shape of the declaration tells you the shape of the expression in the code.  From there it's just remembering how the various subexpressions are typed:

```
Expression        Type
----------        ----
        pa        int (*)[N];
       *pa        int [N];
  (*pa)[i]        int
```

---

The array subscript operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - given a starting address `a`, offset `i` elements (not bytes - remember the discussion of pointer arithmetic above) from that address and dereference the result.  This means that if `p` is a pointer, then

```
*p == *(p + 0) == p[0]
```

meaning you can subscript a pointer expression as though it were an array<sup>1</sup>.

So given your declarations

```
int mat[200][9];
int (*p)[9] = mat;
```

then you can index into `p` the same way you can index into `mat`:

```
(*p)[j] == (*(p + 0))[j] == p[0][j]
```

Thus `p[i][j]` yields the same value as `mat[i][j]`.

---

1. Arrays are not pointers, but array *expressions* are converted to pointer expressions as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should read

```
 int (*p)[9];
```

as a pointer to an array of `int [9]` (9 integers). It's a regular pointer, having a type as `int [9]`.

Pointer arithmetic would work just as in case of other pointers, based on the size of pointer, i.e., `sizeof(int[9])`.

That said, for the other question, whenever in doubt, check the data type!

```
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *ptr = (int*)(&a+1);               
    printf("%d %d", *(a+1), *(ptr-1));
    return 0;
}
```

`&a` is if type `int (*)[5]`, so the pointer arithmetic will honor that. `&a+1` points to the first element *after* the entire array.

So, naturally, `ptr` points to one past the last element address. so, by saying `*(ptr-1)` will get you the value at the last element, which is `5`.

Answer (score 0):

think of &a being a pointer to an "item" with the sizeof(int)*5 so when you do plus 1 it will send you to the next element after the array which will be advanced by an offset of 20 bytes so you do the -1 and then cast it as an int to get the last variable of the array.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. is it a regular pointer, or some kind of a special pointer to a block of memory that is `9*sizeof(int)` big?

It is a pointer to an array with type `int [9]`. Which in turn is indeed `9*sizeof(int)` bytes big.

> 2. how do I refer to such syntax?

They are called array pointers or pointer to array. You can think of it as "a pointer to the whole array", not to be confused with "pointer to the first element in an array".

> 3. lets say I have a given matrix:
>
> ```
> int mat[200][9];
> int (*p)[9] = mat;
> ```
>
> how would pointer arithmetic work with it, for example, if we were to increase p

Just like any pointer type, `p` is assigned to point at the first element in the `int [200][9]` array. The first element is is an array `int [9]` and a pointer to such an array is `int(*)[9]`.

> 4. how do I cast to such type?

Like any type, though they aren't compatible with pointers to arrays of different size or type, nor are they compatible with `int*`.

> 5. the next code's output is `2 5` and I think that it has a link to the special syntax I've shown above. can someone explain to me why isn't the output `2 1`?

Normally, arrays decay into a pointer to the first element whenever used in an expression. That's what happens here `*(a+1)`, the `a` decays into a `int*` and pointer arithmetic + 1 leaves us pointing at the 2nd element.

One of the very few exceptions to this array decay rule is the operand of the `&` address-of operator. So in the expression `&a`, the array `a` does *not* decay. Instead we get the address of it, in the form of a pointer to array `int (*)[5]`.

`&a + 1` then gives pointer arithmetic on a pointer to array. Like any pointer arithmetic, the `1` means the size of one pointed-at item, in this case `sizeof(int [5])`. So we end up pointing out-of-bounds by one of the original array - which is fine, we may point there as long as we don't de-reference the pointer.

The `(int*)` cast is very fishy and bad practice, since `(int*)` is not compatible with `int(*)[5]`. However, C allows us to do wild and fishy casts as long as we don't de-reference the data through the wrong type. But `*(ptr-1)` then goes to the last item of the array and de-references it. This abuses a special rule in the C pointer/type system which allows us to access ("lvalue access") an actual object though a different pointer type, as long as what's stored in that memory location is actually of the type used for the access. Since the `5` that's actually stored there on the physical memory address is an `int`, it works.

Comment: Now the real question is if the person who wrote the code was a C veteran or just got it right by luck. To write code like this, you need to be aware of the two special rules mentioned: point 1 item past the end of an array, where a single variable is treated as an array of 1 item -  and the effective type/strict pointer aliasing rule. That is generally not the case with intermediately skilled C programmers - in case you aren't aware of the mentioned rules, please refrain from wild & dangerous pointer casts.

Comment: Bit of Googling got me ["Geek for geeks"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-language-2-gq/advanced-pointer-c-gq/). Given the average quality of that site, I would assume they just got it right by luck indeed (though everything on the linked page seems correct far as I can see).